# Why is malloc() considered a library call and not a system call?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Why is malloc() considered a standard C library function and not a system call? It seems like the OS is responsible for handling all memory allocation requests.

Comment: `malloc` is a library function that can be implemented in many ways, including some that might use syscalls (or not).

Comment: @4386427 And then check the implementation for some bare-metal environment :)

Comment: The distinction between "library call" and "system call" has become more than a bit artificial.  On almost all OSes, **every** call your C code makes is a **library** call that may map to zero, one or more actual system calls inside the **library** function.  Even glibc's `syscall()` itself is [implemented as a **library** function (albeit in assembler)](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscall.S.html).  Unless you're writing your own assembler to invoke the actual system call instruction(s) for your CPU directly, you're calling a **library** function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would certainly be *possible* to implement `malloc` and `free` as system calls, but it's rarely if ever done that way.

System calls are calls into the OS kernel. For example, on POSIX systems (Linux, UNIX, ...), `read` and `write` are system calls. When a C program calls `read`, it's probably calling a wrapper that does whatever is needed to make a request to the kernel and then return the result to the caller.

It turns out that the most efficient way to do memory management is to use lower-level system calls (see `brk` and `sbrk`) to expand the current process's data segment, and then use library calls (`malloc`, `free`, etc.) to manage memory within that segment. That management doesn't require any interaction with the kernel; it's all just pointer manipulation performed within the current process. The `malloc` function will invoke a system call such as `brk` or `sbrk` if it needs more memory than is currently available, but many `malloc` calls won't require any interaction with the kernel at all.

The above is fairly specific to Linux/POSIX/UNIX systems. The details will be a bit different for Windows for example, but the overall design is likely to be similar.

Note that some C standard library functions *are* typically implemented directly as system calls. `time` is one example (but as Nick ODell points out in a comment, a `time` call can often be performed without interacting with the kernel).

Comment: Pendantic note: the `time` function isn't a great example of this, since it can be gotten without a syscall if vDSO is enabled: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316074/why-dont-linux-utils-use-a-system-call-to-get-the-current-time The general point is still correct, though. Great post!

Comment: @NickODell I am legally obligated to point out that you misspelled "Pedantic".

Comment: Really good answer, thank you. In hindsight, reaching out to the OS when malloc is used seems very unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like the OS is responsible for handling all memory allocation requests.

Well, both yes and no

It actually depends more on your specific system than it depend on C.

Most OS allocates memory in trunks of some size. Typically called a page. The page size may differ. And on a specific system there may be several supported page-sizes. 4K is a typical page-size on many systems but huge page much bigger may be supported.

But yes... at the end of the day there is only one entity that can allocate memory. The OS. Unless you are on bare-metal where other code can handle it - if even supported.

> Why is malloc() considered a standard C library function and not a system call?

The short answer is: Because `malloc` isn't a OS/systemcall. Period.

To elaborate a bit more. One `malloc` call may lead to a systemcall but the next `malloc` may not.

For instance: You request 100 bytes using `malloc`. `malloc` may decide to call the OS. The OS gives you 4K. In your next `malloc` you request 500 byte. Then the "layer in between" can just give the 500 bytes from the trunk already provided by the previous syscall.

So no... memory allocation via `malloc` may not lead to any syscall for alocation of more memory.

It's all very dependent on your specific system. And the C standard doesn't care.

But `malloc` is not a syscall. `malloc` uses other syscalls when needed.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the OS is responsible for handling all memory allocation requests.

For performance reasons, it's not a good idea to ask the OS for memory every time the program needs memory. There are a few reasons for this:

1. The OS manages memory in units called pages. Pages are typically 4096 bytes long. (But some architectures or operating systems use [larger](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages) pages.) The OS can't allocate memory to a process in a chunk smaller than a page.

   Imagine you need 10 bytes to store a string. It would be very wasteful to allocate 4096 bytes and only use the first 10. A memory allocator can ask the OS for a page, and slice that page into smaller allocations.
2. A system call requires a context switch. A context switch is expensive, (~100 ns on x86 systems) relative to calling a function in the same program. Again, it is better to ask for a larger chunk of memory, and re-use it for many allocations.

> Why is malloc() considered a library call and not a system call?

For some library calls, like `read()` the implementation in the library is very simple: it calls the system call of the same name. One call to the library function `read()` produces one system call to `read()`. It's reasonable to describe `read()` as a system call, because all the work is being done in the kernel.

The story with `malloc()` is more complicated. There's no system call called `malloc()`, and the library call `malloc()` will actually use the system calls `sbrk()`, `brk()`, or `mmap()`, depending on the size of your allocation and the implementation you're using. Much of the time, it makes no system call at all!

There are many different choices in how to implement `malloc()`. For that reason, you'll see many different competing implementations, such as [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/), or [tcmalloc](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc).

Answer (score 0):

> Why is malloc() considered a standard C library function and not a system call?

Because it's part of the C standard library.

> It seems like the OS is responsible for handling all memory allocation
> requests.

It's not. An operating system typically allocates some memory space for a given process, but how the memory is used after that is up to the process. Using the standard library for things like memory allocation insulates your code from the details of any given operating system, which makes your code a lot more portable. A given implementation of `malloc` might ultimately make a system call to obtain memory, but whether it does or doesn't or does some of the time is an implementation detail.

Comment: To be fair, `brk/sbrk` calls that are used in some `malloc` implementations are indeed syscalls

Comment: @4386427 Re "*At the end of the day the OS is responsible for all memory allocation.*", This is not always the case. Though, to be fair, the systems where this isn't the case probably don't have a malloc.

Comment: @4386427 Right, I am pointing that it does not align with the claim "*An operating system typically allocates some memory space for a given process, but how the memory is used after that is up to the process.*". `brk/sbrk` is changing the initial allocation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. From a C programmer's point of view, how `malloc` is implemented shouldn't matter. An important feature of the standard library is that it insulates programmers from OS-specific details like that. The fact that you even mention `brk` and `sbrk` suggests that you have a very unix-centric view, and nothing wrong with that, but there are plenty of systems out there that don't have those calls. Heck, if I'm working on an Arduino, `malloc()` still works even though there's no real operating system at all.

Comment: @Caleb I know all of it and agree, and you can review my comments to the questions to convince yourself :) I am just pointing out that your answer is containing some categorical claims that are not always true.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've added a bit more explanation which may help satisfy your concerns. The OP's question is pretty broad, so IMO an answer that's broadly correct even if the particulars might vary from one system to another seems appropriate.